# Python Spark: How to join 2 datasets containing >2 elements for each tuple

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to join data from these two datasets, based on the common "stock" key

```
stock, sector
GOOG Tech

stock, date, volume
GOOG 2015 5759725
```

The join method should join these together, however the resulting RDD I got is of the form:

```
GOOG, (Tech, 2015)
```

I'm trying to obtain:

```
(Tech, 2015) 5759726
```

Additionally, how do I go about reducing the results by the keys (e.g. (Tech, 2015)) in order to obtain a numerical summation for each sector and year?

Comment: Please include the code you used to attempt to solve the problem in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import struct, col, sum

#sample data
df1 = sc.parallelize([['GOOG', 'Tech'],
                      ['AAPL', 'Tech'],
                      ['XOM', 'Oil']]).toDF(["stock","sector"])
df2 = sc.parallelize([['GOOG', '2015', '5759725'],
                      ['AAPL', '2015', '123'],
                      ['XOM',  '2015', '234'],
                      ['XOM',  '2016', '789']]).toDF(["stock","date","volume"])

#final output
df = df1.join(df2, ['stock'], 'inner').\
    withColumn('sector_year', struct(col('sector'), col('date'))).\
    drop('stock','sector','date')
df.show()

#numerical summation for each sector and year
df.groupBy('sector_year').agg(sum('volume')).show()
```

Output is:

```
+-------+-----------+
| volume|sector_year|
+-------+-----------+
|    123|[Tech,2015]|
|    234| [Oil,2015]|
|    789| [Oil,2016]|
|5759725|[Tech,2015]|
+-------+-----------+

+-----------+-----------+
|sector_year|sum(volume)|
+-----------+-----------+
|[Tech,2015]|  5759848.0|
| [Oil,2015]|      234.0|
| [Oil,2016]|      789.0|
+-----------+-----------+
```